# Discord.js message includes

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi im currently adding some new features to a bot and it's been going great with some amazing progressions each day. I ran into an issue that i can't seem to solve even though i feel like the solution is right in front of me. In my code i have an if statement to check if a user has more matches won than 22 in the database, if so they are allowed to equip a certain background if not it returns an error message. I tried to do another if statement to check if a certain user is trying to run the command by matching their discord ID and for some reason it runs both the if statements when doing either command even though i used message.content.includes to specify what arguments it should look for in the command. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please Include the code you've tried.

Comment: What do you think `if (message.content.includes('Cam'), userInfo.matchesWon.length < 22)` does?

Comment: If you want multiple expressions to be met you'll need to use the and operator (`&&`). Make sure you get the basics of JavaScript and programming down before you use a library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the mozilla docs:

**The comma operator (,) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.**

This means that only the second operand in each if statement is being returned, ignoring `message.content.includes()`.

Changing the `,` to `&&` should fix the issue.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator